# Providers and Modules childs

Tags: angular

I do not undestand why i need set a provider in an parent component if anyway i will import it later in a child component as a service.

This is the service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class AService {
 doSomething(){
    return 'i am a service';
 }
}
```

This is the parent:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AService }  from './a-service';
import { ChildComponent }  from './child.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-parent',
  directives: [ChildComponent],
  providers:[AService],
  template:'<my-child></my-child>'
})

export class ParentComponent{ }
```

The angular2 documentation says: [link here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html#!#registering-providers-in-a-component)

> Look closely at the providers part of the @Component metadata. An instance of the HeroService is now available for injection in this HeroesComponent and all of its child components.

But, in the definition of the child component, i need import the service anyway. If I dont, it will crash:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AService }  from './a-service';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-child',
  template:'<p> this is the {{service_returned_data}}'
})

export class ChildComponent{ 
  constructor(private _service: AService){}
  service_returned_data=_service.doSomething();
}
```

Can anybody explain me the meaning of this?

Answer (score 2):

providers and import are two entirely different concepts.

- Providers define the **scope** of **an instance** of the service in your tree of injectors (resembles the structure of your components and directives)
- imports identify types uniquely within your entire application for **static type checking**, autocompletion and Angulars DI uses the type information on constructor parameters as key to look up providers to fetch an instance and pass it to the constructor.

Comment: You are right. Angular respond my question a few lines down: [link](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html#!#focus-on-the-constructor).

Comment: **Basically the meaning of this is make the service a singleton**.